# Docker Container Vuejs Vite Exposing non-public IP

Tags: docker, vuejs2, vite, amazon-lightsail

I just migrated a VueJS app from the vue-cli to vite. I am attempting to deploy a PoC instance to a little Amazon Lightsail instance like I have in the past. It is not production, but available for some stakeholders to take a look at and poke around in.

However, when I deploy the docker container, it seems to be exposing the internal Lightsail IP instead of the public. When I change the vite.config.js preview settings to host: PUBLIC_IP it throws an error saying it cannot bind. When I leave it 0.0.0.0 it binds to the internal IP address.

Locally running the containers on my laptop works just fine and I can access locally.

Relevant vite.config.js:

```
export default defineConfig({
preview: {
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    strictPort: true,
    port: 8080,
},
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
    web:
        build: [CONTAINER.REGISTRY.LOCATION]
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
        volumes:
            - "./app:/app"
        command: sh -c "npm update --save && npm install && npm run serve"
        environment:
            HOST: 0.0.0.0
```

Relevant Package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "serve": "vite preview"
  },
```

Output on the Lightsail instance:

```
APP serve
vite preview

Local: http://localhost:8080/
Network: http://172.17.X.X:8080/
```

I had a dependency issue that made it so I have to move away from vue-cli unexpectedly so I have only been at this today. I have managed to get through many other challenges, but this one has me a bit stumped.